# How do I get my link background to go beneath it during hover?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background

I can't figure out how to make it so that when I hover over a link, a small orange triangle appears below the link along a line i already have. The html and css this pertains to is below.

-----HTML-----

```
<div id='links'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>interests</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>game</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>about</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

-----CSS-----

```
div#links {
background: url('images/links_bg.gif') no-repeat right;
height: 75px;
margin: 0px;
}
div#links ul {
float: right;
list-style: none;
margin: 48px 35px 0px 0px;
}
div#links ul li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
}
div#links ul li a {
color: #e5e4e4;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;;
}
div#links ul li:hover {
background: url('images/link_triangle.png') no-repeat;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I also have a background image for all of the links. I think the problem is that since each link is basically a box around the text you can't give it a background that extends past that box. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post http://imgur.com/ links for the background images?

Comment: Sure you can give it a background that extends past the box, just give the box padding. Maybe it'd be easier to understand the issue if you'd put up a demo, say, at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have a jsFiddle almost ready to go when he can provide the images: http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/MG3e9/. Feel free to fork and answer as I go to bed.

Comment: How do I use jsfiddle.net? Never have before.

Comment: @kojiro do you know how to put images onto jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to mess around with paddings and what not for a while. Got it eventually. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do instead is use jQuery to show the images in a separate `div` below the links using `position: absolute` on `mouseover`.

Comment: I don't know jquery yet. Kinda just starting out.

Comment: @DylanButh Fair enough. This is probably better in CSS, but I can't help you til I get those images.